# Is it possible to force .NET to use the unicode version of P/Invoke method in its own code

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, .net-4.8

For example if i call the method `System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory`, within the .NET code the Win32 API method `CreateDirectory` from kernel32.dll is called.

In the .NET source code the method is declared as following:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, BestFitMapping = false)]
internal static extern bool CreateDirectory(
  string path,
  Win32Native.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes);
```

CharSet is set to CharSet.Auto. It seems that always the Ansi version is called.

My question is if i can force .NET to use the unicode version instead of the Ansi version.

Comment: I seem to remember that 64-bit always uses Unicode, can't find a reference to that though. In fact I think it uses it on all version of Windows above XP. How do you know the Ansi version is called?

Comment: Where do you see this source code? The current source code calls `CreateDirectoryW` directly https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/b42188a8143f3c7971a7ab1c735e31d8349e7991/src/libraries/Common/src/Interop/Windows/Kernel32/Interop.CreateDirectory.cs#L20 referenced from here https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/b42188a8143f3c7971a7ab1c735e31d8349e7991/src/libraries/Common/src/System/IO/FileSystem.DirectoryCreation.Windows.cs#L16 and in turn from here https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/Directory.cs

Comment: I see this source code in the Directory.cs, method InternalCreateDirectory. 
This method calls Win32Native.CreateDirectory which is declared as mentioned above.
I'm on .NET 4.8

Comment: .NET Core uses the wide version, prior to Core it seems to not:  https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/mscorlib/microsoft/win32/win32native.cs#L1396

Comment: Which source code are you looking at? And how do you know it's calling the Ansi version if it's set to `Auto`?

Comment: I just step into the code with F12 and i assume it is downloaded from the symbol server and the jetbrains decompiler does the rest of the work.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that always the Ansi version is called.

How do you know this?  Are you using .NET core on Linux or something? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/charset

In any case, instead of this:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, BestFitMapping = false)]
```

This:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
```

Alternatively, all Win32 APIs are really macros that map to either an `A` postfixed version of `W` postfixed version for ANSI and WIDE (unicode) respectively.

So calling `CreateDirectoryW` directly should work:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
internal static extern bool CreateDirectoryW(
  string path,
  Win32Native.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes);
```

Comment: First of all to answer your question, i am using .NET framework 4.8

Maybe you get me wrong, i know how to declare the unicode version of a Win32 Api method, my question is about the native .NET code which uses CharSet.Auto inside.